# libpcap error : truncated dump file; bogus savefile header

Tags: c++, libpcap

I'm using a standard and simple program to read all packets for an open_file.
open_file means that i'm using tcpdump in order to capture all traffic on the eth0 interface and write it all to a file.
when running my program I get the following error code :

```
"truncated dump file; tried to read 16 header bytes, only got 11
sleeping
bogus savefile header
sleeping
bogus savefile header
..
..
..
(and so on)"
```

this is the important part of the program :

```
handle = pcap_fopen_offline(pFile, errbuf);
while (true) {
            if (pcap_loop(handle,num_packets , got_packet, NULL)== -1){
                    std::cout << pcap_geterr(handle)<< std::endl;
            }
                    sleep(1);
                    std::cout << "sleeping" << std::endl;

        }

    pcap_close(handle);
```

so, i'm using sleep(1) in order to let the data to keep flowing before iterating again.

is anybody has a clue why do I get this error?
It looks like I happens when my program gets to the end of the file and start reading packet that the tcpdump did't finish writing. 
After this error pcap_loop can't read any other packets from the open file.

Comment: If you get to the end of the file, what other packets do you want to read?

Comment: Since it's an open file, more packets will be written to the file. that's the reason for the sleep(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is anybody has a clue why do I get this error?

Because tcpdump writes the file using libpcap, and libpcap uses the "standard I/O" routines such as `fwrite()` to write, and those routines buffer data in memory and only write it to the file when

1. the buffer fills up;
2. the file is closed;
3. the application does an explicit "flush" operation;

and tcpdump doesn't, by default, do a "flush" after every packet, so, at any given point, part of a packet might be written to the file and part of it might still be in memory.

I.e., what you're doing is not guaranteed to work, and is not supposed to be guaranteed to work.

Wireshark does something similar, *but* the program Wireshark runs to do packet capturing (dumpcap) has a pipe to Wireshark, and, for each group of packets it writes to the file, it does a "flush" after the group of packets and sends Wireshark a message saying "Here are N more packets", and Wireshark doesn't try to read to the end of the file when it's doing a capture, it just tries reading the number of packets it's been told are there.

Tcpdump doesn't have a mechanism like dumpcap's (and dumpcap's mechanism is a private protocol between Wireshark/TShark and dumpcap, which is not guaranteed to remain the same from Wireshark release to Wireshark release, so you can't safely use dumpcap).

Newer versions of tcpdump *do* have a "-U" flag, which causes a "flush" to be done after every group of packets written to the file.  However, if a group of packets is big enough, this might still cause multiple writes to be done to the file, so that there might be an interval during which the file has part of a packet.

Short version: what you're trying to do won't work and probably can't be made to work.  What exactly are you trying to do?  (Not "read from a file to which tcpdump is writing" - you're presumably doing that for some other reason; there might be a better way to get that done.)

Comment: I have a bigger system that uses tcpdump to write traffic to a file. I am a smaller module that parses the file. this hirarchy must stay like this and I can't use libpcap function pcap_open_live()

Comment: The -U flag did solve the problem though. Thank you so much for the help